# Urban Hydrology Using With GIS

Tags: arcgis-10.1, hydrology, flood

I'm researching how can I create a model urban floodplain depending on rainfall. And Which programme should I use? I want to show floodplain depending on temporal and spatial distribution on study areas. Which are parameters I should know? Soil characteristic, evaporation, moisture, climate, rainfall interval, rainfall intensity, drainage system, infrastructure pipes etc. But, I haven't got sufficient information.

Comment: About parameters, you can go at it from two ways. 1) Use the data you have, analyze how good model you can create (and do it). If the result is good enough, you're done. If not as good and detailed as you hoped, get more data. 2) Define what data and level of detail you need for your analysis and make sure you have it before you start. Exactly what you need is depending on the purpose of your analysis. Not having enough information is a pseudo-state, either you use what you have or you make sure you get more data. There's no in-between.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Hec-ras](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-ras/), there is an extension to use in ArcGis.

Comment: Thank you but I tried hec-ras,hec-georas and hec-hms. They are not enough for this model.

Comment: @zeynep In what aspect are they not enough? I doubt you will find a model that includes all the parameters you list above.

Comment: It is not necessary to be each parameters. It should include most of the parameters for a real study.